# Method and variable have non-static needs to be static error

Tags: java, static-methods, static-variables

I have some problem code I pulled from a book that should not be saying a non-static variable or method needs to be static.  The error on the variable comes without me changing anything with that code.  The error in the method came after I added code to it but now even when I take the code out it still gives me the error.  I have the variable error in Product.java in the getFormattedPrice method in the format currency statement.  The method error is in the main method when I call writeProducts.

```
public class Product
{
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    public Product(String code, String description, double price)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price ;
    }

    public Product()
    {
        this("", "", 0);
    }

    public void setCode(String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public static String getFormattedPrice()
    {
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return currency.format(price);
    }

    public String getFormattedPrice(double price)
    {
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return currency.format(price);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        if (object instanceof Product)
        {
            Product product2 = (Product) object;
            if
            (
                code.equals(product2.getCode()) &&
                description.equals(product2.getDescription()) &&
                price == product2.getPrice()
            )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Code:        " + code + "\n" +
               "Description: " + description + "\n" +
               "Price:       " + this.getFormattedPrice() + "\n";
    }
}
```

main method

```
public class XMLTesterApp
{
    private static String productsFilename = "products.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Products list:");
        ArrayList<Product> products = readProducts();
        printProducts(products);

        for(Product p2 : products){
            System.out.println(p2.getPrice());
        }
        Product p1 = new Product("test", "XML Tester", 77.77);
        products.add(p1);
        writeProducts(products);
        System.out.println("XML Tester has been added to the XML document.\n");


        System.out.println("Products list:");        
        products = readProducts();
        printProducts(products);


        products.remove(2);
        writeProducts(products);
        System.out.println("XML Tester has been deleted from the XML document.\n");


        System.out.println("Products list:");
        products = readProducts();
        printProducts(products);

    }

    private static ArrayList<Product> readProducts()
    {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        Product p = null;
        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        try{
            FileReader fileReader = new 
                FileReader("C:\\Users\\AndrewSpiteri\\Documents\\Classes\\Baker\\CS 242\\java\\netbeans\\ex_starts\\ch19_ex1_XMLTester\\products.xml");
            XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(fileReader);

            while(reader.hasNext()){
                int eventType = reader.getEventType();
                switch(eventType){
                    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                        String elementName = reader.getLocalName();
                        if(elementName.equals("Product")){
                            p = new Product();
                            String code = reader.getAttributeValue(0);
                            p.setCode(code);
                        }
                        if(elementName.equals("Description")){
                            String description = reader.getElementText();
                            p.setDescription(description);
                        }
                        if(elementName.equals("Price")){
                            String priceString = reader.getElementText();
                            double price = Double.parseDouble(priceString);
                            p.setPrice(price);
                        }
                        break;
                    case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                        elementName = reader.getLocalName();
                        if(elementName.equals("Product"))
                            products.add(p);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                reader.next();                
            }
        }
        catch(IOException | XMLStreamException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        // add code that reads the XML document from the products.xml file

        return products;
    }

    private void writeProducts(ArrayList<Product> products)
    {
        XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        try{        
            FileWriter fileWriter = new 
                FileWriter("C:\\Users\\AndrewSpiteri\\Documents\\Classes\\Baker\\CS 242\\java\\netbeans\\ex_starts\\ch19_ex1_XMLTester\\products.xml");
            XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(fileWriter);
            writer.writeStartDocument("1.0");
            writer.writeStartElement("Products");
            for(Product product : products){
                writer.writeStartElement("Product");
                writer.writeAttribute("Code", product.getCode());
                writer.writeStartElement("Description");
                writer.writeCharacters(product.getDescription());
                writer.writeEndElement();
                writer.writeStartElement("Price");
                double price = product.getPrice();
                writer.writeCharacters(Double.toString(price));
                writer.writeEndElement();
                writer.writeEndElement();
            }
            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException | XMLStreamException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static void printProducts(ArrayList<Product> products)
    {
        for (Product p : products)
        {
            printProduct(p);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void printProduct(Product p)
    {
        String productString =
            StringUtils.padWithSpaces(p.getCode(), 8) +
            StringUtils.padWithSpaces(p.getDescription(), 44) +
            p.getFormattedPrice();

        System.out.println(productString);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're calling it from a static context e.g. the main method, it will need to be static, unless you have an instance of the class in your scope. I'm not sure what you're aiming for with this question. Are you trying to say that the book is wrong?

Comment: `writeProducts` isn't static. The error is pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `static` from this method.

```
public static String getFormattedPrice()
{
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    return currency.format(price);
}
```

You get the error because `price` in an instance variable, not a static class variable.

And add `static` to `private void writeProducts` in order to call `writeProducts` from another static method.